# cut more than one url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder with all my files. The folder includes a file with the profile and file with the wall in a social network that I am building. The link for the profile is for example : **profile.php?email=test@test.com** and displays the profile for the test user. I use htaccess to change link:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /social_network/profile.php?email=$1
```

I also have the wall page called wall.php. I want insetad of **social_network/wall.php** to display : **social_network/welcome**  any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a new rule for handling `wall`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# wall requests
RewriteRule ^welcome/?$ /social_network/wall.php [L,NC]

# profile requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /social_network/profile.php?email=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a perfect answer. In case I want to add a url for messages for the link: messages_else.php to displayed as social_network/messages which is the process? thanks again!

Comment: For that you can add a new rule just below `RewriteEngine On` like this: `RewriteRule ^ messages/?$ /social_network/messages_else.php [L,NC]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^welcome$ /social_network/wall.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /social_network/profile.php?email=$1
```

To some extent you can test RewriteRules here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/